# Nano case for Hp 110 250 Series Motherboard 762025-001

Tags: motherboard, case

I am searching for a case that is as small as possible but can fit a Hp 110 250 Series Motherboard 762025-001 and a HDD or SDD (and maybe a case fan).
The motherboard has a build in energy supply so that there is no need for a power adapter. That is also the part that is confusing me.
I thought maybe a HTPC case or a small cube is working, but the motherboard holes are not fitting with what I found.
Any ideas for such a "special" board?

Comment: Since OEMs like HP get their boards custom made, you will find it difficult to just screw one into any box. Their cases are made for their boards. You'll most likely have to do some custom work to make it fit with off the shelf parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Probably the Node 202 based on price, but making your own could be pretty cool.

Although really it depends how much you care about size vs. cost vs. your own time, since you're not exactly trying to cram a lot of hardware in.

## Compatibility

Looking at an overhead view of the motherboard, it clearly shares the same mounting holes as mITX.

[image]

[image]

So any case with mITX support–such as any one from the the 15 pages [here](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/case/#f=8&xcx=0)–will work. Not sure what case you were trying that didn't work; most cases these days have support for mITX.

## Off the shelf cases

The thing about a case is that it's ultimately a matter of taste, and I can't decide that for you. With that, I'm going to provide a range of good cases and let you choose what you like. Most of this is copied from my previous answer [here.](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8705/general-mini-itx-recommendations/8748#8748)

### Very small cases

These cases are generally described as "artisan": made by specialized companies in low volumes, with extremely good build quality, at extremely high prices.

#### [Dr. Zaber Sentry](http://zaber.com.pl/sentry/#home)

**$235 (TBD), 6.9L, 305mm video card, 5x2.5", SFX-L PSU**

[image]

It's the epitome of a very small case: extremely expensive, extremely tiny, extremely good build quality (primaily powder coated steel), pretty good compatibility with a few things to keep in mind, and runs a bit hot, but generally extremely good. One big issue though: you can't buy one. [They're apparently targeting Q1 2018](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/849582-where-can-i-buy-a-dr-zabers-sentry-case/?do=findComment&comment=10595833), but for now, I can't recommend what you can't buy.

#### [NFC Skyreach 4 MINI](http://nfc-systems.com/skyreach-4-mini/)

**$199, 5.0L, 215mm video card, 2x2.5", special**

It's the smallest case in this category. Note that video card compatibility is very limited, drive mounting is limited, and most of all, PSU compatibility is virtually nil, with only two PSUs listed (a [$95 400W DC-DC](https://www.hdplex.com/hdplex-400w-hi-fi-dc-atx-power-supply-16v-24v-wide-range-voltage-input.html) and a [$58 200W DC-DC](https://www.sfflab.com/products/dynamo-mini-dc-atx-200w)); however, these should be non-issues for you.

[image]

#### [DAN A4-SFX](https://www.dan-cases.com/dana4.php)

**$255 (TBD), 7.2L, 295mm video card, 3x2.5", SFX-L**

[image]

You like shoeboxes? I like shoeboxes! Made under contract by Lian-Li of mostly aluminum, it's (IMO) the prettiest case on this list. But again, it's not for sale yet (just preorders), and I can't recommend what you can't buy.

### Pretty small cases

These cases are a step up in size from the very small cases, and benefits to match. These are largely cheaper, easier to work with, have better support, and are actually available to purchase!

#### [NCASE M1](https://www.sfflab.com/products/ncase_m1)

**$195, 12.6L, 317mm video card, 3x3.5" + 3x2.5", ATX (SFX-L highly recommended)**
[image]

The sort of "daddy" of small cases, the NCASE M1 is the last artisan case on this list, and one of the older ones here. It has incredible support for hardware (even a slimline optical drive!), while being spacious enough to keep things from getting too toasty.

#### [Fractal Design Node 202](http://www.fractal-design.com/home/product/cases/node-series/node-202)

**[$80](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/GsZ2FT/fractal-design-case-fdcanode202bk) or [$130 with a 450W PSU](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/XbKhP6/fractal-design-case-fdmcanode202aaus), 10.2L, 310mm video card, 2x2.5", SFX-L**
[image]
It's an extremely popular choice, and a good one! Nothing stands out really except for the very reasonable price.

#### [Silverstone FTZ01](http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=533) [RVZ01](http://www.silverstonetek.com/raven/products/index.php?model=RVZ01), [RVZ02](http://www.silverstonetek.com/raven/products/index.php?model=RVZ02), and [RVZ03](http://www.silverstonetek.com/raven/products/index.php?model=RVZ03)

**[$85](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/GCfp99/silverstone-case-rvz01b) to [$130](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/P9Wrxr/silverstone-case-ftz01b), 14L, 330mm video card, 1x3.5" + 2-4x2.5", SFX-L**

All very similar with nothing too stand out; the RVZ03 trades the slimline optical slot and 3.5" mount for an extra 4x2.5" mount and RGB lighting.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### [Silverstone ML08](http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=607)

**[$70](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/bvfmP6/silverstone-case-sstml08b), 12L, 330mm video card, 2x2.5", SFX-L**

[image]

It's literally based on the RVZ02, but smaller, cheaper, less drive mounting, and with an optional handle!

#### Honorable mention

The Silverstone SG05 and Silverstone SG06 are neat too, but much boxier. The Fractal Design Array R2, Lian-Li Q09, Raidmax Element, SilverStone SG07 and SG08, and Xigmatek Eris EN6305 are no longer in production, though they would make perfectly good boxes if you can find them.

### Not as small cases

They're bigger with support for more things! They're also **much quieter.** Carrying handles are a must here, since you said that regular transport was an integral part to this build. These cases seem to have largely fallen out of favor as smaller cases take over the mITX sector, but I've put them here anyways.

#### [BitFenix Prodigy](https://www.bitfenix.com/global/en/products/chassis/prodigy/)

**[$60](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/KsTmP6/bitfenix-case-bfcpro300kkxskrp), 26.4L, 317mm video card, 5x3.5", ATX**

[image]

[HardwareCanucks put it best:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZXDgjVY_EI) It's a beautiful chassis at a great price with a few minor compromises for that goal.

#### Honorable mentions

The [Corsair 380T](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/graphite-series-380t-portable-mini-itx-case) is a great case, but unfortunately, it no longer appears to be in production, and second hand prices for it are absurd. The [Silverstone CS01B](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/qGcMnQ/silverstone-case-sstcs01b) is also rather neat, but the 190mm max video card length kills any recommendation. The [Cougar QBX](https://cougargaming.com/en/products/cases/qbx/) and [Fractal Design Define Nano S](http://www.fractal-design.com/home/product/cases/define-series/define-nano-s-window) are beautiful and compact, but too large to not have a carrying handle and still be intended as portable IMO.

## Your own case

The great thing about building a PC is that you're free to use whatever components you'd like, including building your own! Because you're not trying to cram a lot of hardware in, if you're really bent on getting the smallest case possible, it might be worth looking at rolling your own. The off-the-shelf cases are created with the intention of being used with more "normal" motherboards and usually have to accommodate a PSU and GPU–things that aren't issues in your case. mITX is an open standard, and it doesn't take much to make a basic case.